# Is it illegal to broadcast/stream music for non-commercial purposes?

Tags: copyright, european-union

I have a simple question that I haven't found any answer on, on the web.

I have a lot of purchase music on Google Play and I want to create a internet radio just for fun, for non-commercial purposes. Is that breaking the copyright law in European-Union(Sweden), or I need to buy a special license for every song or album?

Comment: Have you read the Terms Of Use of your download? This is almost guaranteed to break them, and certainly if they're via Google distribution, and you will be breaking contract as well as copyright law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the [Google Play Terms of Service](https://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html) it is against the policy:

> #### 4. Rights and Restrictions
>
> **License to Use Content.** After completing a transaction or paying the applicable fees for Content, you will have the non-exclusive right, solely as expressly permitted in these Terms and associated policies, to store, access, view, use, and display copies of the applicable Content on your Devices or as otherwise authorized as part of the Service for your **personal, non-commercial use only**. All rights, title and interest in Google Play and Content not expressly granted to you in the Terms are reserved. Your use of apps and games may be governed by the additional terms and conditions of the end user license agreement between you and the Provider.
>
> **Violation of License Terms.** If you violate any of the Terms, your rights under this license will immediately terminate, and Google may terminate your access to Google Play, the Content or your Google Account without refund to you.
>
> **Restrictions:** You may not:
>
> - display (in part or in whole) the Content as part of any public performance or display even if no fee is charged except (a) where such use would not constitute a copyright infringement or violate any other applicable right or (b) as specifically permitted and only in the exact manner provided.
> - sell, rent, lease, redistribute, **broadcast, transmit**, communicate, modify, sublicense, transfer, assign any Content to any third party including with regard to any downloads of Content that you may obtain through Google Play except as specifically permitted and only in the exact manner provided.
> - use Google Play or any Content in conjunction with any stream-ripping, stream capture or similar software to record or create a copy of any Content that is presented to you in streaming format.
> - use Content as part of any service for sharing, lending or multi-person use, or for the purpose of any other institution, except as specifically permitted and only in the exact manner provided.
> - attempt to, or assist, authorize or encourage others to circumvent, disable or defeat any of the security features or components that protect, obfuscate or otherwise restrict access to any Content or Google Play.
> - remove any watermarks, labels or other legal or proprietary notices included in any Content, or attempt to modify any Content obtained through Google Play, including any modification for the purpose of disguising or changing any indications of the ownership or source of Content.

The key parts are the "personal, non-commercial use only" which means that you may only use it for your personal enjoyment and that you may not "broadcast, transmit, communicate..." any content to any third party (aka listeners on a station).

For more information on obtaining a broadcast license, you'll have to [search Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=license+to+broadcast+music), there are a lot of good links on the first page.